# Alcor card reader problem

Tags: usb

I am using Elementary OS Freya with generic kernel 3.19
I couldn't able to use my card reader. Nothing happens when I insert a card.

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:3701 Pixart Imaging, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:030d Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3286 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg output:

```
[ 1259.152178] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 1259.246192] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[ 1259.246198] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1259.246203] usb 1-1.1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 1259.246206] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1259.246210] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 058F63666433
[ 1259.246619] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1259.246803] scsi host10: usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
[ 1260.374288] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1260.374842] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1262.042005] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 31116288 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[ 1262.043071] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1262.043075] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1262.044119] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1262.044127] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1266.149979] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1266.149988] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1266.149997] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] <<vendor>> ASC=0xff <<vendor>> ASCQ=0xff
[ 1266.150000] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1266.150003] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1266.150012] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1266.150017] buffer_io_error: 18 callbacks suppressed
[ 1266.150020] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1267.688688] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1267.688698] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]
[ 1267.688704] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[ 1267.688707] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1267.688710] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1267.688723] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1267.688729] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1267.688786] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1267.688826] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1267.688874]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1267.692495] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1271.799765] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1271.799775] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1271.799783] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] <<vendor>> ASC=0xff <<vendor>> ASCQ=0xff
[ 1271.799786] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1271.799790] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1271.799800] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1271.799806] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1273.338295] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1273.338304] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]
[ 1273.338309] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[ 1273.338312] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1273.338315] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1273.338325] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1273.338330] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1273.338387] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1273.338426] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1273.338457]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1274.931516] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1274.931524] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1274.931533] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] <<vendor>> ASC=0xff <<vendor>> ASCQ=0xff
[ 1274.931536] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1274.931539] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1274.931549] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1274.931554] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1274.932851] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1274.932859] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1274.934470]  sdb: unable to read partition table
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are disk read errors (`Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0`). You might want to try another USB port and verify that your disk can be read on another machine / another card reader.